# Some Questions about "Sign in by ..." that the social sites offers

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-plus

Im working on a site, and I'm thinking to let people sign in through Facebook, G+, Twitter.

I have some questions:

1: Am I allowed to display other's 'simple' profiles for everyone? Im thinking to by example "sign in with facebook", store the facebook id, and then on the 'active list' where all users are displayed, make a simple _target link to the facebook profile?

What I would be using is a little thumb of their picture, name and then the facebook id to link to the profile by  facebook.com?profile.php?id=...

Everyone who enters my site would be able to see the active list, and therefore all these peoples names and thumb profile pictures..

2: About the above, Would I need to ask for more permission than the "basic profile information"?

3: A facebook page. Can they login? And is there a way to detect whether the client is logging in by a page or a normal profile? Or maybe pages only work when you have a profile on facebook, so is there a way to verify that the profile that signs in owns (is administrator) of that specific page?

Comment: I don't know who -1'd it, but generally on Stackoverflow we answer coding questions.  For how do I program it, see programming.stackexchange.com.  For questions about admining a facebook account, see http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbDevelopers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. is possible
2. Nope, basic info is fine.
3. Yes, you can detect if they're a page or not by looking at the "user" data and see if that id is in their list of `me/accounts`, and yes you can check to see if the user is an admin of the page as it is part of the signed_request.

I generally dislike multiple questions in one, so I will not be answering any followup questions to this that are posted inline, as comments or as edits to the original question. Sorry.